# A lot of beautiful qualities I would find within you

Tags: word-order, subjunctives

> *A lot of beautiful qualities I would find within you.*

I am wondering about the grammatically of the sentence structure. Specifically, is the placement of "I would find" okay?

Comment: context, more information, more clarity needed!

Comment: Your first attempt asked: _"Grammatically or the way I wanted to mean it... does it sounds wrong?"_ I closed that as **Unclear what you're asking**, with a comment explaining why. You then changed the question to *Grammatically is it wrong?* At that point, I reopened the question, but reclosed it for a different reason (proofreading). Finally, you identified your source of confusion, as requested, so I reopened the question. However, I still think the question, as it stands now, could use some improvement, as per the guidance provided [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439).

Comment: This is too ambiguous to permit an answer. Is it supposed to be a complete sentence, with the Direct Object moved to the front? Or is it a phrase with a relative clause *[that] I would find within you*? What exactly are you trying to say?

Answer (score 1):

> A lot of beautiful qualities I would find within you.

This is grammatically correct,  however to a British person it sounds like you haven't found these qualities in them yet.

I'm not sure what you are trying to mean in this sentence... I would guess that you actually are trying to say:

> You have a lot of beautiful qualities?

Comment: This American English speaker concurs: it's in the subjunctive so it hasn't actually happened.  Also, while it's perfectly correct, it's unusual and, depending on one's tastes in such things, either poetic or flowery.

Comment: It reminds me of Theodore Roethke's poem "I knew a woman lovely in her bones", the first verse. "Of her choice virtues only gods should speak// Or English poets who grew up on Greek// (I'd have them sing in chorus cheek to cheek)."

Comment: @Codewsitcher Well, it *may* be subjunctive; or it may be a volitional *would*, which is archaic enough to sort well with a preposed Direct Object. ... I love the Roethke quote!

Comment: WendiKidd, Thanks to confirm... Yes absolutely I wanted to mean that "You have a lot of beautiful qualities... and I may would that when I would meet you." I want to assure that person about this (for future when would meet).

Comment: Codeswitcher, thanks to get it well. It's a bit poetic way wanted to say, rather than directly confirming about their qualities. Thanks for adding those lines of poem.